# Navbar isn't collapsing on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make the same behavior as the YouTube app:
the navbar has to collapse when scrolling down (the tabs remain) and it has to reappear when scrolling up.

I'm stuck on the first step, using the react-native-navigation component (https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

Here I define my screen navigation options:

```
public static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        ...MyScreen.getDefaultNavigationOptions(),
        tabBarIcon: (options) => {
            return (<Icon
                name="person" size={RN.Platform.OS == "ios" ? 30 : 25} style={{ color: options.tintColor }} />
            );
        },
        title: t("My Screen")
    };
}
```

And here are my navigation options :

```
public static getDefaultNavigationOptions() {
    return {
        headerLeft: null,
        headerRight: null,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: ColorManager.colors.primaryColor
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: ColorManager.colors.text,
            fontSize: 25,
            marginLeft: 15,
            width: "100%"
        },

        navBarHideOnScroll: true,
        expendCollapsingToolBarOnTopTabChange: false,
        drawUnderTabBar: true,
        topBarCollapseOnScroll: true,

        title: ""
    };
}
```

My renderView parent is a ScrollView, but nothing happens when I scroll down (the navbar seems fixed).

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if react needs to abide by the same syntax rules as Jquery and JavaScript, but there should be a semicolon at the end of your comma separated arguments. so, the "tittle" and the "width" arguments should end with a semicolon.

Comment: No that's not required with react

Comment: maybe it needs something in the title then. Its hard to tell what javascript method its using under the hood.